# How to set coordinates for sprite correctly in Phaser?

Tags: jquery, coordinates, phaser-framework

I have a code:

```
 w = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
 h = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

 holdLeft = game.add.button(w/2.892, h/1.3092, 'holdLeft', this.holdLeft, this);
```

And I have problems setting coordinates to this sprite, for example, I don't know exactly where this one should be and I need to think out some coordinates but then I always need to change it again and again

Maybe there is some another easier way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

I will really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to position your button according to the game size, you should probably use game.width/game.height which are more reliable.

Now if you want to adapt your button's position according to the screen size, there's no magic solution. [Here's a generic article](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-different-screen-sizes/) about the topic for instance. You should decide from which origin you'll position each UI element, be it a screen corner, the center of the screen, a gameplay object, etc. and anticipate how things will turn out if the resolution changes.

For example, if you want to have a square pop-up in the center of your screen, you'll do something like:

```
var popup = game.add.sprite(game.width/2, game.height/2, 'popup');
popup.width = 400;
popup.height = 400;
popup.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
```

Now to give it a title, you'll probably want to position it according to the popup itself:

```
var text = game.add.sprite(popup.x, popup.y + 10, 'Hello world');
text.anchor.set(0.5, 0);
```

etc. There's no one-solution-fits-all but make it clear what uses what as the origin and hopefully you won't have surprises when resizing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Phaser.Button, just like images and sprites, has an `anchor` property, which is by default set at (0, 0) (top left corner). You can set it to half the width and half the height of the button like this:

```
holdLeft.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
```

http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Button.html